# Generate different strings from a JSON using split python

Tags: python, json, split, pyrebase

I'm trying to retrieve the values ​​of a JSON extracted from firebase, JSON is:

```
{"data": "01/01/2000", "destino": "JPY", "nome": "teste", "origem": "BRL", "taxa": 1.4000000000000004, "valordestino": 14.000000000000002, "valororigem": 100.0}
```

I want to insert each of these values into a QTableWidget. Considering this, I thought of breaking JSON into a string for each value in the database *(e.g. data, destino, nome, origem, taxa, ...)* Basically what i want is:

```
teste[0] = 01/01/2000
teste[1] = JPY
teste[2] = teste
teste[3] = BRL
teste[4] = 1.40
teste[5] = 14.00
teste[6] = 100
```

I tried to split the JSON using a `split`  in every `:` found in the JSON, however this not worked.

```
usuarios = db.child("operacoes").get()
for usuario in usuarios.each():
      teste = json.dumps(usuario.val())
      teste.split(':')
      print(teste)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want ? Have the list of keys, the list of values ? You didn't tell us what was the expected thing

Comment: `teste.split()` returns a list. You'd have to do it that way: `teste = teste.split(":")`

Comment: @azro I've editted my question to show how my output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

```
usuarios = db.child("operacoes").get()
for usuario in usuarios.each():
      teste = list(usuario.val().values())
      print(teste)
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about `values`. It will be very useful!